# Getting out of the closed circular id reference loop in mysql typrorm?

Tags: mysql, typescript, typeorm

I have the following tables:

**administrators**

| id | passwordId | createTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

**passwords**

| id | currentPassword | oldPassword | olderPassword | administratorId | createTime | updateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

To create an administrator, I have to provide the **passwordId**, and to create a password I have to provide the **administratorId**.

I am in a closed-loop state, and I can't get out.

Here are my entities:

```
@Entity("administrators")
class Admin extends BaseEntity {
  // Changed to 'Admin' for uniqueness
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
    type: "int",
    name: "id",
  })
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", name: "password", select: false })
  @OneToOne(() => Password, (password) => password.id)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "passwordId" }) // Corrected join column name
  password: Password;
}

@Entity("passwords")
class Password extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: "int", name: "id" })
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", name: "currentPassword", length: 255 })
  currentPassword: string;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", name: "oldPassword", length: 255, nullable: true })
  oldPassword: string;

  @Column({
    type: "varchar",
    name: "olderPassword",
    length: 255,
    nullable: true,
  })
  olderPassword: string;

  @Column({
    type: "int",
    name: "administratorId",
    transformer: fromToStringNumberTransformer,
  })
  @OneToOne(() => Admin, (admin) => admin.id) // Corrected entity reference
  administratorId: number;
}
```

I remember in PHP while using the mysqli object, we used a method to query the database to reserve the next ID for us and fetch it. We can then use this ID right in our code.

How can I create an administrator with a password in typeORM in this case?

Comment: Why does Password need an administrator ID? That is unnecessary.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, I thought it will make querying faster (?)

Comment: Not really. A simple join between admin table and password, with proper indexed columns will work just fine. The modeling itself is conceptually wrong. An administrator as an user has a password, the link is already there. You don't need to hard state that a password belongs to an admin. I would probably not even do this, password fields could be in the user table (unless you have more than one type of user table, which is also debatable).

Comment: @Normal --  You are using `passwordId` for the admin table .. This should be enough to link them .. And the speed will just 
be fine so long as the `id` field in `passwords` is INDEXED -- And as Jorge stated .. I would just put username and pass as **fields** in the users table .. There is no need for a separated table here .. It's unneeded "bloat"

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll remove the reference from the administrator table and keep it in the passwords table. one question, I have modeled other tables around this concept as well. So is it always wrong to have two tables that will point to one another? or _it depends_ ?

Comment: In a one-to-many it is normal .. Meaning that administrator may have MANY passwords .. And you are linking them with a pivot table .. Then it would be appropriate.  But if your admin user has only **one** password .. It's appropriate just to have a single table and make it "wider"